# nil current_user response to json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I found a demo app that implements devise with Backbone. In the layout file, it does this

```
$(function(){
        BackDevise.initialize(<%= current_user.to_json.html_safe %>);
    })
```

If I start the application without being logged in, there is obviously no current_user, but the application doesn't throw an error. Why?  i.e. normally, when I use Devise with Rails, I have to do a lot of `<% if current_user ... %>` checks to see if the user is logged in. Why wouldn't this code need anything like that? Note, the code doesn't (as far as I can see) override the current_user helper provided by Devise, so I would have expected it to throw an exception if I'm not logged in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cause `nil` responds to `to_json` and returns `"null"`